# Trying to defrag computer on Windows 8 but possible virus wont let me open program

Tags: defragment

After trying to open Defrag through command prompt I receive this message

The storage optimizer cannot start because you have insufficient privileges to perform this operation. <0x89000024>

Help Please to regain access.

Comment: What makes you think it's a virus this seems for a system corruption problem

Comment: Have you tried running it with an elevated command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Where you click on "command prompt" instead right-click it and choose "run as administator."  If you have Windows 8.1 installed you can also right-click the Windows Logo in the bottom left of the screen on your task bar and you will also see a Administrator command prompt option there.